# Occasional Exception Unhandled thrown although Break option is deactivated

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, system.net

I've set up my exceptions so that an error in the code

```
        Try
            Using Client As New WebClient
                Client.DownloadFile(sExtract, sDownloadTo)
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print("Failed: " + sExtract)
        End Try
```

isn't throw.

This works fine most of the time, but after like 50-100 of errors, the following exception is shown:

[image]

According to the checkbox state "Break when this exception type is thrown", which is not-activated, this exception shouldn't be shown this way, right?

What might cause this behaviour, and how could I change it so that this exception isn't thrown?

Here is an additional image of the QuickWatch:
[image]

Answer (score -2):

```
   Try
        Dim Client As New WebClient
        Client.DownloadFile(sExtract, sDownloadTo)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.writeline(ex.tostring)
    End Try
```

Comment: Just when I thought it worked, the same exception was thrown again.